# Filtering of associated entity collection in Symfony / Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If I have an associated object that is a collection, I can restrict the results?

For example: Producer entity has the property translations, which contains a collection of other entities (ProducerTranslation).

```
class Producer
{
    protected $id;
    // ArrayCollection
    protected $translations;
}
```

ProducerController:

```
$producers = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('ProducerBundle:Producer')
    ->findAll();
```

Result:

```
Producer
    id: 1
    translations:
        en: ProducerTranslation
        de: ProducerTranslation
```

It's alright. But I want to get only one entity of a language.
Expected result:

```
$producers = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('ProducerBundle:Producer')
    ->findByLocale('en');

Producer
    id: 1
    translations:
        en: ProducerTranslation
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict a sub collection you can use querybuilder like this (assuming locale is a property of ProducerTranslation):

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('p, pt')
    ->from('ProducerBundle:Producer', 'p')
    ->join('p.translations', 'pt')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('pt.locale', ':locale'))
    ->setParameter('locale', 'en')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

That'll get you what you want. Note the select('p, pt') part is important as it will only fetch the items you want into the collection result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just on result you need to use the `findOneBy` prefix:

```
$producers = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('ProducerBundle:Producer')
        ->findOneByTranslations('en');
```

You have to use the right name of your attribute here you have `translations` so it will be `findOneByTranslations`.