# How to filter OneToMany relationship' entity based on specific field when querying main entity

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, entity, relationship

So I have this basic blog that contains articles (`AppBundle\Entity\Courrier`) and comments (`AppBundle\Entity\Reaction`). These two entities are bound together through a `OneToMany` relationship. Here are their definitions:

#### Courrier.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Courrier
{
    // ...

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reaction", mappedBy="courrier")
     */
    private $reactions;
```

#### Reaction.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Reaction
{
    const STATUS_ACCEPTED = 0;
    const STATUS_PENDING = 1;
    const STATUS_MODERATED = 2;
    const STATUS_TRASHED = 3;

    // ...

    /**
     * Thread of this comment
     *
     * @var Courrier
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Courrier", inversedBy="reactions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="courrier_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $courrier;
```

with

```
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;
```

My problem is that when I'm querying `AppBundle:Courrier` repository, I want to filter `AppBundle:Reaction` based on `$status`. That means doing something like :

```
$courrier = $doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Courrier')->findOneWithReactionsFiltered($slugCourrier, Reaction::STATUS_ACCEPTED)
```

So I built this very repository method and here it goes:

```
public function findOneWithReactionsFiltered($slug, $status)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->leftJoin('c.reactions', 'r')
        ->where('c.slug = :slug')
        ->andWhere('r.status = :status')
        ->setParameters([
            'slug' => $slug,
            'status' => $status,
        ])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

But the return value of this method (that is `$courrier`) is filled with `Courrier` entity with its `Reaction`s regardless of the `$status`.

I also dumped the SQL query :

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id0, c0_.name AS name1, c0_.slug AS slug2, c0_.envoi AS envoi3, c0_.intro AS intro4, c0_.courrier AS courrier5, c0_.reponse AS reponse6, c0_.published AS published7, c0_.like_count AS like_count8, c0_.recu AS recu9, c0_.image_id AS image_id10, c0_.categorie_id AS categorie_id11 FROM courrier c0_ LEFT JOIN reaction r1_ ON c0_.id = r1_.courrier_id WHERE c0_.slug = 'yaourt-cerise' AND r1_.status = 0;
```

Finally, here's a small dump of the table:

```
mysql> select r.id, r.status, c.slug from reaction as r left join courrier as c on c.id = r.courrier_id order by c.slug asc;
+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
| id    | status | slug                               |
+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
| 15533 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15534 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15535 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15536 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15537 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15538 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15539 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15540 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15541 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15526 |      0 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15542 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15527 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15543 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15528 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15544 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15529 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15545 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15530 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15546 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
| 15531 |      1 | yaourt-cerise                      |
+-------+--------+------------------------------------+
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select both entities to hydrate then into the collection on query.

E.g. you need to add another select for the r alias:

```
->addSelect('r')
```

Then your collection will be correctly loaded and filtered from your query.

For more info see my answer below:

[Filtering of associated entity collection in Symfony / Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665738/filtering-of-associated-entity-collection-in-symfony-doctrine/34666648#34666648)

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your solution does not work when there is no `Reaction` attached to `Courrier`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: No problem, your left join is too restrictive, you always need to allow null - otherwise your left join is basically just a regular join. E.g.         ->andWhere('r.status = :status OR r.status IS NULL') - syntax may not be 100% right but that's the gist of it :)

Comment: And now, how about `Courrier` that hold only `Reaction` with `$status` different from what desired? The query returns nothing when I want, at least, `Courrier`. How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

It's the intended behavior. By querying the `Courrier` repository you'll get all entities which have at least one `Reaction` with the status you provide. `Reactions` are not immediately joined, but the Doctrine proxy you get from the repository fetches all of them as soon as you access its `$reaction` `ArrayCollection`.

You can get what you want in two ways:

1. Use the `Reaction` repository and execute the query there, maybe joining the `Courrier` so you don't have to query again for it;
2. Create a method in `Courrier` entity to filter collection results based on a criteria. It could be something like that:

   ```
   public function getReactionsWithStatus($status)
   {
       return $this->reactions->matching(
           Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('status', $status));
       )->toArray();
   }
   ```

**NOTE: below is the outdated reply since the question evolved**

When replacing parameters, you should pass them without the colons. Change

```
->setParameter(':courrier', $value)
```

to

```
->setParameter('courrier', $value)
```

and you should be good to go.

Do not forget to do the same thing for `reaction`.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.. Thanks tho!

Comment: there might be another problem in how you pass parameters to your query. You should choose unique placeholder names for your parameters, otherwise they get overwritten during the foreach loop. Try using something unique for your parameter names like for example a numeric index.

Comment: Just updated with new code that takes out this placeholder problem.

Comment: The produced query seems correct. Are you absolutely sure you're passing the correct parameters? The Symfony profiler should also be able to print the executable query (with substituted parameters).

PS: you probably forgot to update parameters of your find* function.

Comment: Your hint helped me in finding that the effective runnable query returns no results. It's the case when there is no `Reaction` with the desired `$status`. I'll update my question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I took option n°1. I didn't want to put any logic into my entities. Thanks!